# Problems on connecting Android Studio project to Firebase database

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I have tried to connect my project on Android studio to Firebase database. While trying to do so I have added some code lines to the app gradle file. Then I got an error that I can't solve for a week...
Although this error I can run the app on the emulator so I continued the process of getting connected to Firebase.
After I finished that, I have tried to add something to the database- and no success.
Please if you know how to fix this problem- help me :)

app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rotem.bepart"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error:[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIhCu.png)

The error text:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

Comment: move courser to that error. Then press alt + enter. it will suggest correct versions for u.

Comment: It doesn't suggest that. It gives me the option to 'provide feedback on this warning'.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is your problem. please share the connection code with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Your gradle will look like

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
.
.
.
```